# Spring Boot + Liquibase + Gradle + Testcontainers / Can't find config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, liquibase, testcontainers

So, I've been trying to start a migration from Maven to Gradle at my work but I've now run into a serious problem which I can't seem to wrap my head around.

I basically just wanna run some simple liquibase migrations for my tests, for which I spin up two testcontainers. One for a rabbitmqexchange and one for a postgres DB.

I've set up the postgres container using a little workaround described here: [Testing Spring Boot Applications with Kotlin and Testcontainers](https://rieckpil.de/testing-spring-boot-applications-with-kotlin-and-testcontainers/)

I've tried it a thousand ways and scoured all related questions but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is...

Here is the setup using Gradle 6.7.1:

`build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.20"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring") version "1.4.20"
    id("org.liquibase.gradle") version "2.0.4"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:3.0.9.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit:3.0.9.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.0.0")
//    liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.0.0")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.18")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.0")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.15.0")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.15.0")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:rabbitmq:1.15.0")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.15.0")
}

description = "my-project"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

application {
    mainClass.set("path/to/the/main/class")
}

tasks.named<Test>("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

tasks.register<Copy>("copyJarToTargetDir") {
    mustRunAfter("build")
    val outputJar = "$buildDir/libs"
    val targetDir = "$projectDir/target"
    from(outputJar)
    include("*.jar")
    into(targetDir)
}

tasks.register<Delete>("deleteTargetDir") {
    mustRunAfter("clean")
    delete("$projectDir/target")
}

tasks.named("build") {
    finalizedBy("copyJarToTargetDir")
}

tasks.named("clean") {
    finalizedBy("deleteTargetDir")
}
```

The Base test:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Testcontainers
class PartnerEdgeServiceApplicationBaseTests {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var vehicleRepository: VehicleRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var vehicleStreamChannel: VehicleDataChannel

    @LocalServerPort
    private val port: Int = 0

    @Test
    fun `check application`() {
        println("Howdy, Partners!")
    }
}
```

And the test in question:

```
class MessageSinkTest : ApplicationBaseTests() {

    companion object {
        @Container
        val rabbitMQContainer = RabbitMQContainer("rabbitmq:alpine")
        @Container
        val postgresContainer: KPostgreSQLContainer = KPostgreSQLContainer("postgres:10.11-alpine")

        @JvmStatic
        @DynamicPropertySource
        fun properties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgresContainer::getJdbcUrl)
            registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgresContainer::getPassword)
            registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgresContainer::getUsername)
            registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.addresses", rabbitMQContainer::getAmqpUrl)
            registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.username", rabbitMQContainer::getAdminUsername)
            registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.password", rabbitMQContainer::getAdminPassword)
            registry.add("spring.liquibase.url", postgresContainer::getJdbcUrl)
            registry.add("spring.liquibase.user", postgresContainer::getUsername)
            registry.add("spring.liquibase.password", postgresContainer::getPassword)
        }
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should extract the vehicle data and persist in the DB")
    fun test1() {
        val id = "id"
        val locationId = 1L
        val numberPlate = "Some plate"
        val buildSeries = "VW_TIGUAN"
        val fuel = 75
        val fuelType = "GASOLINE"

        vehicleStreamChannel.input().send(
            GenericMessage(
                VehicleDataStreamDto(
                    id = id,
                    locationId = locationId,
                    numberPlate = numberPlate,
                    buildSeries = buildSeries,
                    fuel = fuel,
                    fuelType = fuelType
                )
            )
        )

        val persistedVehicle = vehicleRepository.findByIdOrNull(vin)
        assertEquals(id, persistedVehicle?.id)
    }
}
```

And the application.yml:

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /my-project
streaming:
  retries: 5
  concurrency: 15
  amqpGroupName: my_project
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
  liquibase:
    url: ${spring.datasoure.url}
    user: ${spring.datasource.username}
    password: ${spring.datasoure.password}
    contexts: environment-name-will-be-placed-here
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  cloud:
    stream:
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          vehiclestream:
            consumer:
              declareExchange: true
---
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local
```

When I run the test I get the following logs:

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:99)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:313)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: The file classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml was not found in
- a bunch of paths
```

my db.changelog-master.xml is at the following location (from the project's root):

```
src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

Hence, the error does not really make sense or I'm missing something (which is obviously the case...). Anyways, any kind of help is much appreciated!!

**UPDATE:**

so, I did make a little change. I swapped out these two dependencies `implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.0.0")` for `liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.0.0")` and removed the `jpa.properties` on my application.yml. I did get a different error:

```
{"@timestamp":"2020-11-29T09:05:08.612+01:00","@version":"1","logmessage":"SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01","logger_name":"org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"WARN","level_value":30000,"vin":"vin"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-11-29T09:05:08.614+01:00","@version":"1","logmessage":"ERROR: relation \"vehicles\" does not exist\n  Position: 290","logger_name":"org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"vin":"vin"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-11-29T09:05:08.617+01:00","@version":"1","logmessage":"HHH000327: Error performing load command","logger_name":"org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener","thread_name":"Test worker","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"stack_trace":"org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Exception thrown while invoking VehicleDataSink#processData[1 args]; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a];
```

Comment: will you please change the path to `classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml` and check ?

Comment: same result, different path: ```Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: The file classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml was not found in
    - ...```

Comment: The [document](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/springboot/using-springboot-with-maven.html) says `classpath:db-changelog.xml` and did a sample project just to check and its working. So I am not sure where you went wrong

Comment: Yea, I seem to be missing something gradle specific but thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for future reference: The problem was not anything gradle/liquibase specific. It was simply the fact, that I created the directories `db/changelog` in one step in Intellij, which created one dir `db.changelog` instead of `/changelog` being the child of `db`. After splitting that up in two separate steps, everything is working out fine!